# How to store Mapbox GL markers in ngrx?

Tags: angular, ngrx, mapbox-gl-js

Because Mapbox [doesn't store references of markers](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5821#issuecomment-356704579) I decided to keep track of them myself by storing them in ngrx. The problem is that the whole application crashes.

The following code crashes the application:

```js
const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
.setLngLat([
    parseFloat(event.longitude),
    parseFloat(event.latitude)
  ])
.setPopup(popup)
.addTo(this.map);

const pin: Pin = {
    id: id,
    status: 'free',
    marker: marker
}

this.store.dispatch(addPin({pin}));
```

Some errors i get:

> [ERROR freeze@http://localhost:4200, Error: microTask 'Promise.then', Uncaught TypeError: "macroTask"]

while it doesn't crash if i replace 'marker' with `null`.

```js
const pin: Pin = {
    id: id,
    status: 'free',
    marker: null
}
```

This makes me think that it is not possible to store a Mapbox marker in ngrx. Is this true, and if so how does one store markers in an Angular application in such a way that another component has access to them?

I hope my question is clear, and if not let me know and i will try to clarify it.

Comment: You haven't included all your code. What is `addPin`?

Comment: just some ngrx action, i didn't add it because it didn't seem that useful. But since asking this question I removed this code because i couldn't find a way to make it work.